# Does polynomial generated by repeated application of matrix divide characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a square matrix $A\in \mathbb C^{n,n}$ and a vector $v\ne0$, the vectors
$$
v, Av, A^2 v, \dots, A^n v
$$
are linearly dependent. Let now $m\le n$ be the smallest number such that 
$$
v, Av, A^2 v, \dots, A^m v
$$
are linearly dependent. 
Then there are coefficients, not all of them zero, such that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^m a_i A^iv=0,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
p(A)v=0
$$
for $p$ given by $p= \sum_{i=0}^m a_i t^i$.

My question is: does this polynomial divide the characteristic polynomial $p_A$ of $A$?

Of course, $p$ and $p_A$ share a non-trivial factor. I think a proof of the claim above can be achieved using Jordan decomposition, but it looks like it would be complicated. Is there a more elementary proof? Does such a proof also work for other fields different from $\mathbb R,\mathbb C$?

(Using this polynomial is the way how Axler proves existence of eigenvectors for the complex case and existence of small invariant subspaces for the real case. )

Comment: It'd be clearer to use $p_v$ instead of $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of $m$, the coefficient $a_m$ must be nonzero. So, we may assume that $p$ is monic.

Note that $V=\operatorname{span}\{v,Av,\ldots,A^{m-1}v\}$ is an invariant subspace of $A$ and $p(A)A^kv=A^kp(A)v=0$ for every integer $k\ge0$. Hence $p$ annihilates the restriction of $A$ on $V$. It must be the minimal polynomial of $A|_V$, for, if the minimal polynomial $q$ of $A|_V$ has degree $r<m$, we will have $q(A)v=0$ and hence $v,Av,\ldots,A^rv$ will be linearly dependent, which is a contradiction to the definition of $m$.

Now, since $p_A(A)=0$, we have $p_A(A|_V)=0$. As $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $A|_V$, it must divide $p_A$.